# BrainTree & Paypal Account Linking

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree

I am using Paypal for payments in my software. According to recent announcements from Paypal, `/payments` end point is deprecated and will not be working anymore. So they have mentioned in their API docs to use BrainTree for payments.

So I created a sandbox account for Braintree and link my Paypal account with it. Both accounts are in Sandbox mode.

According to following documentation, these accounts will not share data because these are in sandbox mode.

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live/ruby

I have some queries regarding this, which are mentioned below:

1. Will these accounts share data with each other in live mode ?
2. If they share data in live mode then,
3. On Braintree, customer creation is required but on Paypal there is no requirement of creating a customer to make payment through card. So how they will share this data ?
4. Will they share cards details also? If yes, then Paypal returns card id which is used for transaction and Braintree returns Payment method token for each card to be used for transaction later. Will these details will also be shared ?
5. How amount can be refunded from Braintree ? Is there any end point for this ? Or for refund I need to use Paypal refund api ?

So, these are some questions which are striking my mind. If anybody can answer these queries, it will be very helpful for me work on Braintree.

Thanks!

Comment: I think these are all relevant questions, though I'm not sure SO is the best place for them. I'd recommend contacting [Braintree's Support Team](https://help.braintreepayments.com) if you have not yet already.

Comment: Braintree is owned by paypal and you connect your paypal account to braintree.  Everything is connected that way.  braintree just makes paypal 10000% times simpler to use